# Setting textview at bottom in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have Textview inside Linearlayout. I want it to be displayed at bottom but it is showing me only at the centre. My xml file is look like the code below. I tried replacing LinearLayout with RelativeLayout but it did't worked.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

 </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomTitle"
    android:text="@string/app_logo_bottom"
    android:textColor="@color/logo_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_size"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomVersion"
    android:text="@string/app_version_info"
    android:textSize="@dimen/version_size"
    android:textColor="@color/version_color"
    android:background="@color/version_bkgrd"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/version_spacing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any one have idea?

Comment: its not taking as textview property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May This help you:

```
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/black">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomTitle"
    android:text="@string/app_logo_bottom"
    android:textColor="@color/logo_color"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_size"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewBottomVersion"
    android:text="@string/app_version_info"
    android:textSize="@dimen/version_size"
    android:textColor="@color/version_color"
    android:background="@color/version_bkgrd"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/version_spacing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"></TextView>

 </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try this worked for me :

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

Comment: Please add more comment

Comment: Why should one try that?

Comment: New syntax from from flex

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
android:gravity="bottom|center"
```